# What is the wavefunction of a traveling particle?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

The following animation (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)) depicts the wavefunction of a free particle traveling in space:

[image]

Aside from the (beautiful) picture, the actual wavefunction is not given for this traveling particle.

What is the wavefunction that will produce a traveling wave like the above?

EDIT: Propagating square modulus of a wavefunction using time and space varying a + bi.

[image]

Comment: Try to solve the Schrodinger equation for a free particle

Comment: It's likely a Gaussian times a plane wave.

Comment: See equation 5.17 here: https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/~golwala/ph125ab/ph125_notes_l15.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an exercise you probably did in your first QM course for a 1D Gaussian wavepacket.  Non-dimensionalize constants $\hbar$ and *m* to 1, and pick convenient momentum and width.

Then you may confirm the free TISE
$$
i\partial_t \psi = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2\psi 
$$
is readily solved by
$$
\psi =(2/\pi)^{1/4} {1\over\sqrt{1+2it}}~\Large e^{-\frac{(x-i)^2}{1+2it} -1}.
$$

Rewrite the space-dependent part of this in polar form, i.e., in terms of an evolving real magnitude/envelope and a (rotating!) phase,
$$
\psi  =(2/\pi)^{1/4} {1\over\sqrt{1+2it}}~\Large e^{-\frac{(x-2t)^2}{1+4t^2} } e^{ 2i\frac{x-t+tx^2}{1+4t^2}} .
$$
Does it evoke the figure you see spiraling and translating in broadening envelope?

Check that, ignoring the non-exponential prefactor, the envelope center moves with constant speed 2 (naturally) and broadens with time. The phase at the wavepacket center rotates uniformly.

---

***Response to the comment of the OP  requesting clarification***

As indicated, only the exponents are rearranged, to yield the polar form.
$$
-\frac{(x-i)^2}{1+2it} -1= -\frac{(x-i)^2 (1-2it)+1+4t^2}{1+4t^2}  \\
= -\frac{(x^2-1)(1-2it) +1+4t^2 -2ix(1-2it)}{1+4t^2} \\
= -\frac{ (x-2t)^2 -2i(x-t+tx^2)}{1+4t^2},
$$
indeed.

Comment: thank you vm. i am trying to separate the real and imaginary parts of Psi, but my algebra isn't what it used to be, and I can't quite remember how to separate the real and imaginary parts of the Psi above (because of the sqrt(1+2it) appearing in the coefficient). If you could give a hand and add the final a + bi expansion for Psi after separating all the real and imaginary parts, please?

Comment: i have opened a thread at Math SE on simplifying Psi:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594471/how-to-separate-a-complex-number-into-standard-a-bi-form

Comment: I could, if you insisted, but, be advised, I explicitly stated I leave the complex coefficient of the exponential alone, and *only* rearrange the exponents!

Comment: what about the i in the coefficient, i can't seem to get at a clean a+bi form because of the i in the coefficient... could i leave out the whole coefficient and just plot the products of the trig exponentials?

Comment: First ignore the coefficient of the exponentials, as it amounts to an insignificant slowly varying *logarithm* when elevated to the exponent, so just plot the exponentials. Then, you may tweak the answer by the slowly varying correction!

Comment: The MSE question might help you. Branches of the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm) are not nice. You might simply look at the branches of the inverse complex square-root...

Comment: thank you vm. I attach the result in the original post, it *is* a self propagating wavefunction!

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know the state vector is determined by
$$\lvert\psi(t)\rangle=U(t,t_0)\lvert\psi(t_0\rangle$$
where $U(t,t_0)$ is the unitary time evolution operator. In the case of a time independent Hamiltonian it is simply
$$U(t,t_0)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H(t-t_0)}$$.
Inserting the identiy operator $1=\int\,dx'\lvert x'\rangle\langle x'\rvert$ in the first equation and projecting onto the $x$-eigenstate gives you
$$\langle x\lvert\psi(t)\rangle=\int\,dx'\langle x\rvert U(t,t_0)\lvert x'\rangle\langle x'\lvert\psi(t_0\rangle\\
\iff \psi(x,t)=\int\,dx'K(x,t;x',t_0)\psi(x',t_0)$$
where we defined the propagator $K(x,t;x',t_0)=\langle x\rvert U(t,t_0)\lvert x'\rangle$. Once you have computed the propagator for your system (represented by a specific Hamiltonian, which implies a specific time evolution operator U), you can compute the time evolution of every initial wave package $\psi(x',t_0)$.

For the textbook-like free particle propagation, one would typically choose $\psi(t_0)$ to be some kind of gaussian distribution. The propagator for the free particle can be computed with complex gaussian integrals and is presented for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_examples:_propagator_of_free_particle_and_harmonic_oscillator). You are left to perform one more gaussian integral with the propagator and your initial condition, the resulting wave package, starting with a gaussian, will still be a gaussian where the peak moves, shrinks and becomes wider over time.